# How do I write an SQL query that retrieves one line per combination of existing unique ids?

Tags: sql

I apologize if this has already been asked or if it's a basic concept - I'm not experienced enough in SQL to know how to succinctly ask it (thus I'm not having much luck searching for it).

Refer to the first row of each table in the first snippet below for an idea of the tables I'm working with.  Table1 and Table3 can have multiple rows with the same table2Id.

Originally, I was just working with Table1 and Table2.  I retrieved one row for each Table1, and all was good.  However, I now need to also retrieve data from Table3 - and the best way I can describe the implications is using the following example:

```
Table1:
id    table2Id   otherData1
abc   123        "otherData"
def   123        "anotherData"

Table2:
id    otherData2
123   "yetAnotherData"

Table3:
id    table2Id  otherData3
!@#   123       "thereCouldntBeMoreData"
$%^   123       "iCantBelieveItsNotData"
```

To fully represent all the data, I'd need 4 rows, one for abc + !@#, one for abc + $%^, one for def + !@#, and finally one for def + $%^ .  If I'm picturing this correctly, my end result would be something to this effect:

```
comboId   t1.id   t2.id   t3.id   t1.otherData1   t2.otherData2      t3.otherData3
abc!@#    abc     123     !@#     "otherData"     "yetAnotherData"   "thereCouldn'tBeMoreData"
abc$%^    abc     123     $%^     "otherData"     "yetAnotherData"   "iCantBelieveItsNotData"
def!@#    def     123     !@#     "anotherData"   "yetAnotherData"   "thereCouldn'tBeMoreData"
def$%^    def     123     $%^     "anotherData"   "yetAnotherData"   "iCantBelieveItsNotData"
```

How would I be able to achieve this?  And thank you in advance for any help you can provide, even if it's just pointing me in the direction of someone else's answer to a similar problem.

Comment: I think you'll find help if you search for "cartesian join"

Comment: I can't upvote yet but thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As WW said, you need a cartesian join. Fortunately that is the default join in SQL. However, since the columns you need to join against have different names, you need `ON` clauses; you should try to make the columns you join have the same name.

To create `comboId` you need to catenate columns; the syntax to do that in SQL Server is `+`, in Oracle `|`, and I think there is a `Concat()` function in MySql. Whenever you ask a question about SQL always tell us which SQL you are using.

In SQL Server it would be:

```
SELECT t1.id+t3.id as comboId, 
       t1.id as 't1.Id', 
       t2.id as 't2.Id', 
       t3.id as 't3.Id', 
       t1.otherData1, 
       t2.otherData2, 
       t3.otherData3
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.id=t1.table2Id
    JOIN Table3 t3 ON t3.table2Id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the result you want but I will be the first to say that its hacky at best, without a primary key and foreign key, I'm not quite sure how to perform a "text-book" join operation.

```
SELECT t1.id+''+t3.id comboId,t1.id t1ID, t2.id t2ID, t3.id t3ID, t1.otherData1, t2.otherData2, t3.otherData3
FROM table1 t1,table2 t2,table3 t3;
```